# Background thread

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, tornadofx

So i want to create an thread which is running until i close the Application.
But i dont know how to do that probably with TornadoFx

This is what i have and i am getting an IllegalThreadStateException.

```
override fun start(stage: Stage) {
    super.start(stage)
    thread {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        println("running")
    }.start()
}
```

Also it is only executed once and than the thread basically stops but this might be because of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your code is doing is starting a thread using the thread builder, and then calling start on that same thread again, hence you get the `IllegalThreadStateException`.

The reason for this is that the kotlin `thread` builder has a `start` parameter, which by default is true. So you can just remove your `.start()` call and the thread would start normally. You could also pass `start = false` to the thread builder and instead call .start() like you did.

However, the thread code you posted will simply wait for 2 seconds, then print "running" and then exit. A thread is not a loop by default, so after 2 seconds and change, the thread has done what you asked it to.

Comment: After reading your answere i was feeling like an Idiot xD. That may have been to mutch work last friday xD.

Comment: Haha, honest mistake if you ask me :)